# What does "vely" means in Korean Instagram names?

Tags: colloquial-language

Not strictly about Korean language but about language habits of Korean people:

I noticed that many Korean Instagram accounts, mostly from girls, contains "vely". What does it mean?

My guess is that it stands for "lovely", but then: why using a shortened version? Where does this tendency originated from?

Here are a few examples (from public Instagrams): [vividvely](https://www.instagram.com/vividvely/), [_velybyeon](https://www.instagram.com/_velybyeon/), and [vely.mom](https://www.instagram.com/vely.mom/)

Comment: I'm living in the US now, so I'm not sure how widespread the term "-블리" is, but during the last presidential election supporters of the progressive candidate 심상정 gave her a nickname of 심블리 (from 심 + 러블리).  So it might be a semi-popular pattern these days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your guess is correct.

That's "lovely" which korean speaking "러블리".

And, some word before 러블리 like "유미(yumi)+러블리(lovely)" is going to be shorten "윰블리(yum+vely)".

So, I think, vely is **Konglish**.